# React Router v4 - How to dynamically use layouts

Tags: reactjs, react-router

To start, I'm both new to React and React-Router. I know the basics of each. Here is my scenario...

I want to have a separate login page with NO layouts at route (/login). When the user logs in, I want to route them to /home. This home page and every other page (beside login) will reuse a layout that contains a navbar and a sidebar.

How do I hide the reusable layout when the user visits the /login route? Do I use a conditional or is there a specific React-Router 'WAY'? I couldn't find examples in the documentation that fit my scenario.

Thanks a bunches!

Comment: why not just have two components? a login thats empty and the other pages have use a template?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how could I render `navbar` and `sidebar` to all components except `login`, then you can check the browser `url`.

There are many ways of doing this, but one of which is like following:

```
<Route path="*" render={props => <Layout {...props} />} />
```

This will appear for all your routes now. Then inside `Layout`, you can check the route, and only render something if the route does not equal to `login`.

```
render(){
  if(this.props.location === "login"){return null}
  ...
}
```

While typing this, you can do it directly in React Router, maybe excluding certain route.